# Limiting the options in a combobox, based on the selected one

Tags: javascript, php, html

I made a similar question yesterday, but couldn't come up with a solution since then, so i went and refined my code a bit to a logic that seemed more plausible to work.
However, it didn't.
I want to have only a couple of options in a combobox available to the user, depending on what option was pre-selected. Here is the Combobox:

```
<SELECT class=caixas id=cbostatus style="WIDTH: 3cm;" tabIndex=25 name=cbostatus onchange= "StatusTest(); hideField();" >   
                            <option selected></option>
                            <option value="Planned" id="optionPlanned" <?php if ($row['task_status']=='Planned') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Planned</option>
                            <option value="Started" id="Started" <?php if ($row['task_status']=='Started') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Started</option>
                            <option value="Available" id="Available" <?php if ($row['task_status']=='Available') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Available</option>
                            <option value="Finished" id="Finished" <?php if ($row['task_status']=='Finished') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Finished</option>
                            <option value="Impeded" id="Impeded" <?php if ($row['task_status']=='Impeded') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Impeded</option>
                        </SELECT>
```

For example, when "Planned" is selected, the only other available option should be "Started". So i went and made a Javascript, for a Onchange Event, like so:

```
function hideField(){
var e = document.getElementById("cbostatus");
 var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

 if( strUser == 'Planned' ) {
    document.getElementById("Impeded").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("Available").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("Finished").style.display = 'none';
 }
}
```

And for some reason, it is wrong. Any ideas?
(Also, i'd aprecciate if you didn't suggest using Jquery, as i have never used before and don't really have time to learn for this)

Comment: If I go from planned to Started, will the select immediately change and show me new options for the change, or will the select only be created and used once?

Comment: only created and used once, the other options would only appear after you submit the form

Comment: I suggest you start with an empty select, and add the options dynamically. I do not have the code around to do it with plain javascript though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with an empty select, and add the options dynamically.

```
var e=document.getElementById("cbostatus");
var strUser = 'Planned'; // get this value from somewhere, maybe a hidden field
if( strUser == 'Planned' ) {
    e.options[e.length]=new Option("Planned", "optionPlanned", true, true);
    e.options[e.length]=new Option("Started", "Started");
} else if ..
```

Comment: just a question, the second line, where you define the strUser as 'Planned', What do you do for the Other values? Do i have to redeclare the var?

Comment: Oh i get it, you created a hidden textbox or something and put this value in there, i see now

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
Html
<select class=caixas id=cbostatus style="WIDTH: 3cm;" tabIndex=25 name=cbostatus>
    <option selected></option>
</select>

jQuery
var insertoption = "";
```

first add options in ready function

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
  insertoption += "<option value='Planned' id='Planned'>Planned</option>";
  insertoption += "<option value='Started' id='Started'>Started</option>";
  insertoption += "<option value='Available' id='Available'>Available</option>";
  insertoption += "<option value='Finished' id='Finished'>Finished</option>";
  insertoption += "<option value='Impeded' id='Impeded'>Impeded</option>";
  $("#cbostatus").append(insertoption);
  insertoption = "";
});
```

This is create your option

and now create onchange function

```
$("#cbostatus").on("change",function()
{
  if($("#cbostatus").val() == "Planned")
  {
    $("#cbostatus").children().remove();
    insertoption = "<option value='Started' id='Started'>Started</option>";
    $("#cbostatus").append(insertoption);
  }
});
```